# Could not load file or assembly for project reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, class-library, project-reference

I have two class library projects and one Web API project. Let it be ClassLibrary1, ClassLibrary2, WebApi.
I add link for Web API  to both  ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2 as a project reference.
In addition, ClassLibrary1 has link to ClassLibrary2 as a project reference.

At the compilation stage, I have no errors, But in runtime, I got the next error:
*Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.*

All Nuget packages have the same versions for these projects.

[image]

Comment: try to check your "CopyLocal" flag and rebuild the project.

Comment: Which is your start project? You cannot run libs, so there should be a driver. Have a look  into that project's bin folder. Are all expected dlls present?

Comment: @Fildor Yep, ClassLibrary1.dll and ClassLibrary2.dll exists in the bin folder.

Comment: @TimurSidoryuk Where can I find 'CopyLocal' flag?

Comment: @HannaHolasava you can find it here: https://pasteboard.co/JnYjeNh.png

Comment: @TimurSidoryuk links to the class libraries are added as project references. It's under Dependencies/Projects, not under Dependencies/References. I set 'Copy Local' and 'Copy Local Satellite Assemblies' to YES, for links in Web API project, it doesn't help

Comment: @HannaHolasava I now check it on my machine. Create .net core 3.1 web api and two class libraries. And it runs good. Also i found, that you don't need to reference at classLibrary2 in your case, because it already included in classLibrary1 reference
Can you provide minimal reproducible example of your problem? Maybe 3 pieces of your projects?

Comment: @TimurSidoryuk thanks you very much for the help. The problem was resolved when I removed the solution from my local storage and reloaded it from the repository. Maybe It was some old settings for the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved when I removed the solution from my local storage and reloaded it from the repository.

Comment: That's great! You can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.
This will help others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the following steps to check the project.

1. Please ensure the target framework of the project and the development platform are the same.
2. Please ensure the reference project comes from:\ClassLibraryx\bin\Debug\ClassLibraryx.dll
3. If there are no problems with the above two, you could try the following steps:

   (1)Remove project references

   (2)Rename two class library projects and rebuild

   (3)Re-add project references